# Why is array_remove (PostgreSQL) not working in this case?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

This is not working correctly:
`SELECT array_remove(array_agg(s1->>'karten'),'8 eich.jpg') from spiele;`

The output:  `["3 eich.jpg","8 eich.jpg","5 sche.jpg","2 herz.jpg","1 laub.jpg","4 eich.jpg","2 sche.jpg","5 laub.jpg","4 herz.jpg","4 sche.jpg"]`

The datatype of s1 is json; s1->>'karten' is an array

Comment: Aber es heißt doch "Gras" ned, "Laub" ;)

Comment: Bei uns (in Südtirol) heißt es Laub ;)

Comment: Interesting... While the horse has no name, it seems that he does have a country :-)

Answer (score 2):

If `karten` refers to a JSON array in the, then `s1 ->> 'karten` doesn't return each element individually, but a one string representing the array. So `array_agg()` doesn't really aggregate multiple values - only one. The result is an array with **a single** element - that happens to look like a JSON array.

You can remove an element from a JSON array if the values is `jsonb` (the recommended data type to handle JSON in Postgres anyway) using the `-` operator:

```
select (s1 -> 'karten')::jsonb - '8 eich.jpg'
```

will return a `jsonb` value that is an without the key `'8 eich.jpg'`.

Unfortunately there is no easy conversion from a JSON array to a native array. Search this site, there are multiple answers for that.